# dagger output java (char)134 doesnt work cp1252

Tags: java, char, show, dagger, cp1252

Normally my program should put out all CP1252 code as chars:

```
System.out.println("actual file.encoding: "+System.getProperty("file.encoding")); // CP1252


for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    System.out.println("Nr.: "+i+ " Symbol: "+(char)i");
}
```

But output is:
(snippet of the whole output!)

```
Nr.: 124 Symbol: |
Nr.: 125 Symbol: }
Nr.: 126 Symbol: ~
Nr.: 127 Symbol: 
Nr.: 128 Symbol: ?
Nr.: 129 Symbol: ?
Nr.: 130 Symbol: ?
Nr.: 131 Symbol: ?
Nr.: 132 Symbol: ?
Nr.: 133 Symbol: ?
Nr.: 134 Symbol: ?
Nr.: 135 Symbol: ?
```

But in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 it is written that 134 is: †

Why doesn't it show † ?

Comment: You are missing that char and string within Java are always UTF-16/UCS-2. The default encoding only applies when converting from bytes to string (or char) and vice versa (without specifying an explicit encoding). That doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

The byte value 134 (or 0x86) in CP1252 is indeed dagger, but `char` in Java is always UTF-16 (Unicode) and in UTF-16 U+0080 - U+00FF (integer codepoints 128 - 159) are non-graphic characters while U+2020 is the character corresponding to CP1252 byte 0x86.

Use `System.out.write(/*int 0-255 only*/i)` to output an already-encoded *byte*. Or less convenient in this case but preferable in others, put the bytes in an array `byte[]` and use `System.out.write(byte[])`.

Comment: hmm. complicated. how is it with the FileWriter. I also can't write the † in my text file xD

Answer (score 0):

ah now it works...
Someone knows which charsets are involed here ? i will find out later but now it is to confusing.
Thank you:
It works with the Unicode U+2020 (hex) which correspond to 8224 :

```
fW.write("Omg it writes † : ");
        fW.write(13);
        fW.write(10);
        fW.write(0x2020);
        fW.write(8224);
        fW.write(13);
        fW.write(10);
```

Output:

```
    Begin:
Omg it writes † : 
††
```

Comment: i assume that my java programm takes the i - my iterator (i hope the word is used correctly..) and converts it into a symbol of utf-16 of 2 bytes. then it is written into the textfile which has a different charset and doesnt understand all utf-16 symbols. maybe it is cp 1252 ..?